# How to run a custom mongodb query in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongo

I have a spring-boot application and I am trying to run this below query using it.

```
db.userActivity.findAndModify(
{ 
   query: { 'appId' : 1234, 'status' : 0},
   update: { $inc: { 'status': 1 } } 
});
```

I did try something like this **but it didn't work**

```
public interface UserActivityRepository extends MongoRepository<UserActivity, String> {

    /**
     * Find all documents in the database
     * @param appId
     * @param status
     * @return
     */
    @Query("{ 'appId' : ?0, 'status' : ?1}")
    public List<UserActivity> findAllDocuments(long appId, int status);

    /**
     * Find all documents by appId whose state is unread
     * and marked them read after reading
     * @param appId
     * @return 
     */
    @Query("db.userActivity.findAndModify({ query: { 'appId' : ?0, 'status' : ?1}, update: { $inc: { 'status': 1 } } })")
    public List<UserActivity> findAndUpdateAllUnreadDocuments(long appId, int status);
}
```

Could you please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered to use mongo db-factory or mongo template ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I should admit I couldn't find a way to update the document using custom mongo query. But, found a way of doing it using java8 streams.

```
 userActivityRepository.save(userActivityRepository.findAllDocuments(1234, 0)
.stream()
.peek((user) -> user.setStatus(user.getStatus() + 1))
.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

The above statement uses `userActivityRepository.findAllDocuments` for fetching the records with a criteria then uses OOTB `MongoRepository` `save(Iterable<S> entites)` method to update the documents.

In place of `$inc` have incremented the `status` field.

This may not be what you are expecting, but just a possible solution if you  wish to implement.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

@Query annotation used for customization of queries only. Use `findAllDocuments` function and implement you update logic. This is the full example: [Spring Boot + Spring Data MongoDB example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-mongodb-example/)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.update

```
public interface UserActivityRepository extends MongoRepository<UserActivity, String> {

    /**
     * Find all documents in the database
     * @param appId
     * @param status
     * @return
     */
    @Query("{ 'appId' : ?0, 'status' : ?1}")
    public List<UserActivity> findAllDocuments(long appId, int status);

    /**
     * Find all documents by appId whose state is unread
     * and marked them read after reading
     * @param appId
     * @return 
     */
    @Query("{ 'appId' : ?0, 'status' : ?1 }")
    @Update("{ $inc: { 'status': 1 } }")
    public List<UserActivity> findAndUpdateAllUnreadDocuments(long appId, int status);
}
```